# Replacing Twitter username with label

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace any twitter @UserName with a {UserName}. I now have the following, replacing @username with USER:

```
$string = "Tweet with @UserName in the string"
echo preg_replace('/@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', ' USER ', $tweet);

// Tweet with USER in the string
```

Is it possible to modify the preg_replace so that its output is

```
Tweet with {UserName} in the string
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$string = "Tweet with @UserName in the string";

echo preg_replace('/\B@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '{${1}}', $string);
```

Note: I added the \B so something like `user@email.com` would not be substituted.

Comment: Reagrding your note: shouldn't an email address be ommitted? It's only usernames I'm looking for :)

Comment: You are right, it is omitting it, but I meant to write would *not* be substituted but left out the not.  Corrected now.

Comment: BTW - I'm trying to implement what you did for usernames, for hashtags. I want to remove all #'s, so "I love #atwt" should be replaced with "I love atwt": preg_replace('/#[^\s]*/i', '${1}', $string). However, this returns only empty brackets ({}). Could you explain me why?

Comment: It is returning empty brackets because you don't have any captures in the regex. A capture is a pattern enclosed in `( )`.  Add that around the actual word and then the `${1}` will work in the replacement.